# html to pdf - 100k to 200k records

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf, mpdf

I am having a data set that has around 1 million records.I will be generating a pdf of more than 100k rows.

I tested MPDF (goes out of memory if I generate around 1800 records using html table) and Fpdf (generates around 40k records - table based).

I don't want to my php application whole of the memory to avoid this issue.

Do we have any other library that I can use in php to export more than 100k rows in a single go?
My code that generates table using mpdf (I have excluded the exports here)

```
   $html="<table>";
              $html.="<tr>";
              $html.="<td> <b> header 1</b></td>";
              $html.="<td> <b> header 2</b></td>";
              $html.="<td> <b> header 3</b></td>";
              $html.="<td> <b> header 4</b></td>";
              $html.="<td> <b> header 5</b></td>";
              $html.="</tr>";

              for($i=0;$i<1740;$i++){
              $html.="<tr>";
              $html.="<td>Data 1</td>";
              $html.="<td>Data 2</td>";
              $html.="<td>Data 3</td>";
              $html.="<td>Data 4</td>";
              $html.="<td>Data 5</td>";
              $html.="</tr>";
         }
        $html.="</table>";

        $mPDF1->WriteHTML($html);
        $mPDF1->Output();
        exit;
```

Comment: Checkout TCPDF library

Comment: TCPDF isn't that good..Doesn't support all the html stuff specially css styles.

Comment: consider getting your data in smaller datasets, loading 200k rows into memory will certainly cause memory problems, so load say 1,000 rows at once, then output to the pdf, and keep getting 1,000 records at a time until there are none left. make sure that you are disposing of the each record set as you go along.

Comment: TCPDF is considerably inferior to MPDF and FPDF. @Augwa's solution is probably the easiest and smartest to implment

Comment: $mPDF1->Output(); if I call it once it outputs the data, if leaves rest of the computation.. Another way could be to save the pdf..keep opening it  and appending the data..

Comment: Thats correct more you use the CSS stuff in PDF more will be the memory consumption, so if you are dealing with large data and do not care much about the CSS then TCPDF works well.

Comment: Avoid HTML parsing/MPDF/TCPDF. Follow the suggested way from @Augwa. Try to work with the low level methods like [Text()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/text.htm) and simulate table borders by drawing them in a single run with [Line()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/line.htm) calls in e.g. the Footer() method.